# How to choose the correct aggregation function?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two dataframes (input and output). The Output dataframe is produced by an unknown model given the input dataframe.

I am trying to build a model (to mimic the unknown model)  to predict **"Issue_no"**  variable which is in the output dataframe (Hence we have a **multiclass classification** problem)

```py
Output Dataframe ,shape(30258, 6)

    node_no  Bandwidth   year   month   day     Issue_no
0    0        10         2019     6      12        7
1    0        10         2019     6      13        7
2    0        10         2019     6      14        7
3    1        10         2019     6      12        11
4    1        10         2019     6      13        11
5    1        10         2019     6      14        8
6    2        10         2019     6      12        4
...
```

```py
Input Dataframe, shape (711432, 58)

    node_no  Bandwidth   year   month   day      hour ... + some numeric columns that their values change every row 
0    0        10         2019     6      12        0
1    0        10         2019     6      12        1
2    0        10         2019     6      12        2
3    0        10         2019     6      12        3
4    0        10         2019     6      12        4
5    0        10         2019     6      12        5
6    0        10         2019     6      12        6
..
```

the problem here is that the Output dataframe is aggreagated on days not hours like The Input dataframe.

So now I know that I should use groupby on **Input** to be able to join it with **Output**.

- how do I know the correct aggregation function? should I use the mean or median etc? How can I test this hypothesis?
- I am confused why the output is this way, doesn't this mean there will be a loss of data if I made any aggregation on the input? is this procedure normal in time series data?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: I thought it was related. Got it.

Comment: Is issue_no simply a count of issues in an input dataframe in a given day? If not, the answer may lay in those columns you ommited.

Comment: No issue _no represents the type of issue, so it is a multiclass classification problem (i have 13 type of issues). I know the final answer is in the omitted columns but I am still confused on how to join both dataframes in order to build the model?